# Dashed vertical separator is not showing up

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create dashed line separator in my View, but As soon as I use this shape drawable as src or background in my `ImageView`, its not visible at all.

Note: I would like to have oval shaped dashed line instead of rectangular shape. How to achieve that? `<corners android:radius="4dp" />` is doing nothing to the shape.

dashed_separator.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:toDegrees="90" >
            <shape
                android:shape="line">

                <stroke
                    android:color="@color/grey"
                    android:dashWidth="4dp"
                    android:dashGap="4dp"
                    android:width="2dp"/>

                <padding
                    android:bottom="5dp"
                    android:left="5dp"
                    android:right="5dp"
                    android:top="5dp" />

                <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            </shape>

        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layerType="software"
    android:src="@drawable/dashed_separator" />
```

Comment: have you tried giving scaleType to centerCrop to imageView

Comment: It would help if you would specify what you want the view to look like.